# Access VBA reading wrong VarType from recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in Access 365 with a subform showing a query of a table from an SQL server.

I have an action, where when a button is clicked, the current filtered view of the above subform is copied to a local table to do simple calculations locally.

I now have a problem where VBA says that a field i VarType = 8 (string). It should be decimal(15,3). I have tried switching to long int and double.

The error i get is seen in the screendump below. The last line in the immediate window show the .Value type. If i change the destination field type to string, it receives an empty string. The values in the fields are 0, which should show in the destination.
I tried using `Cdbl(.Value)` but that also fails. It works for the first 18 rstInsert in the loop. I have the same problem for "ReservedQTY" which is commented out here.

[image]

Edit: Picture 2 shows the with clausul
[image]

Comment: What's the structure of the local table? I assume there's a 'With' statement somewhere?

Comment: @nicomp The local table has the same structure as the SQL table does. I checked it 10 times. And when i change the local table to strings (even though it should be decimal(15,3)), it does not complain. It simply inserts an empty string. When i try to edit the field "ReservedQTY" in the SQL table, and ex puts in "2f", it says that it has to be a decimal number and not a string - So i know the source is a decimal. However, VBA continues to say it is a vartype = 8 / string...

Comment: @nicomp Updated with the "with" statement

Comment: t_BoM_Special is the local copy of the filtered table.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your SQL? Try "select * from t_BoM_special where 1=0" - that should give you an empty recordset with field types matching the source table.  *Please* do not post pictures of code - it makes everything more difficult

Comment: @TimWilliams Alright, the screendump was mostly to show where the error occurs, and that it occurs after a lot of similar statements. I am not sure how changing that SQL will work as it seems like the problem is from the rstSource table and not the destination table.